# Display read only properties

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, metadata, choice-field, document-info-panel, read-only

I am trying to add a 'Security Classification' field to the properties of a document. The requirements are that certain users should be able to change the field at a document library level, or if not possible we would write a script to change this for a library. They want it to be displayed in all documents properties, but not be editable to most users. There's 2 fields that need to be displayed. So far I've tried

- Setting the column to be hidden in the list so that users can't edit it, but then they can't see it either
- Setting it to be optional so that they can see it, but then, obviously they can edit it.
- Setting a hidden column up (choice field) and then a separate lookup column to point to it's value. For some reason the choice field item couldn't be selected in the lookup whether it was hidden or optional
- I've tried setting up the information policy settings to add a dynamic label with the {columnname} or [columnname], but this just seems to come out in plain text

I don't know enough about information management policy settings to get this working and I'm not too sure of the best method to go about it. Another option would be to manually change the DIP and edit forms, but I want these to be dynamically changed when the columns change as there will be loads of veriations to the information required for a document.

Any advise at all would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Using SPD you can create another edit form but restrict access to it so only users with a certain permission level can use the new form.  You could then disable the field in the standard form so normal users can see it but not change it.
2. You could potentially add some jQuery to the form to enable or disable the field depending on the user but getting user permissions could be a challenge.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for responding. How to I go about disabling the field in the standard form so users can see, but not edit it? Is this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Powershell you can set the ShowInNewField and it's companions.

By setting all of them, except for ShowInDisplayForm, to false the field will only be visible when the list is in a plain display mode. In new or edit, the field will be hidden

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield_properties.aspx)